# Is it possible to run after every n hour where n is greater than 23

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-scheduler

Is there a workaround to the limit of the step hour?

[image]

Comment: No, you can't. You can create several scheduler instead

Answer (score 0):

Here is a guide for Kubernetes CronJob that can prove helpful for your use case.[1]

[1] https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/